# What is the use of double pointer to a structure in C?

Tags: c, structure

I recently came across this code for the formation of a queue, using arrays, to store the nodes of a binary tree.

```
typedef struct node{
  int data;
  node *left, *right;
}Node;

Node** createQueue(int *front, int *rear)
{
  Node **queue = (Node **)malloc(sizeof(Node*)*500);
  *front = *rear = 0;
  return queue;
}

int main(){
  int rear, front;
  Node **queue = createQueue(&front, &rear);
  return 0;
}
```

What is the use of the double pointer during the formation of the queue?

This is the link to the whole program:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal/

(Method 2)

Comment: I don't know, ask the programmer who wrote the code.

Comment: It looks like the programmer is trying to make an *array* of 500 pointers to the structure dynamically.

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an object of type `T` as for example

```
T x;
```

when pointer to the object will have type `T *`

```
T *px = &x;
```

In your example there is allocated dynamically an array of `500` pointers to objects of type `Node`. That is each element of the array has type  `Node *`.

```
Node **queue = (Node **)malloc(sizeof(Node*)*500);
```

Function malloc returns the address of the first element of the array.

As each element of the dynamically allocates array has type `Node *` then pointer to an alement of the array will have type `Node **`.

You can imagine it the following way

```
typedef Node * T;

T *queue = ( T *)malloc( sizeof( T ) * 500 );
```

So if you substitute `T` for `Node *` you will get

```
T      *queue = ( T      *)malloc( sizeof( T ) * 500 );
Node * *queue = ( Node * *)malloc( sizeof( Node * ) * 500 );
```

Answer (score 0):

"double pointer" is "a pointer to pointer", from provided excerpt it is hard to tell why programmer decided that he/she needs such a structure.

May be it is for some tasks that need to traverse the whole tree, but do not care about its tree-ness, so this can help avoid recursion (i mean that may need to modify these, for simple traversal a single-pointer would suffice)